# PHP Curl request returns unsuccessful

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to access remote url using Curl.
When curl is executed i got this error

```
   <html style="height:100%">
      <head><META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
         <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
         <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
         <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
      </head>
     <body style="margin:0px;height:100%">
         <iframe src="/_Incapsula_Resource ?CWUDNSAI=24&xinfo=4-13149215-0 0NNN RT(1490255810449 195) q(0 -1 -1 -1) r(0 -1) B12(4,315,0) U18&incident_id=439000400034489515-104043319326605956&edet=12&cinfo=04000000" frameborder=0 width="100%" height="100 %" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px">
            Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: 439000400034489515-104043319326605956
         </iframe>
       </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course Incapsula rejects your request because curl behavior looks like a bot. If you are the admin of the site you can try adding a specific header to curl using -H option and whitelist that header in the Incapsula console.

Just go to the website console and inside the security settings you can find the option to whitelist with following fields:

```
▪   IP - Single IP (1.2.3.4), Range  (1.2.3.4 - 1.3.3.4), Subnet (1.2.3.4/16).
▪   URL - exact URL (/admin); URL which contains all sub-folders (/exmaple/*). Note that it is recommended to seperate between wildcard exceptions and exceptions for exact paths. 
▪   Client app ID - Each of the known client app IDs by Incapsula (Such as Qualys Scanner).
▪   Country - Specific country or continent. 
▪   User-Agent - Each of the known user agents, such Chrome, FireFox, etc. Wildcard (*) can NOT be set here.
▪   HTTP Parameter - Specific HTTP parameter (not a value). Wildcard (*) can NOT be set here.
```

Answer (score 0):

The website is protected by Incapsula.

You can use [incapsula-cracker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39354465/why-scrapy-returns-an-iframe) for bypassing incapsula

thanks Blender for his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39354465/why-scrapy-returns-an-iframe)